# Win8 sleep shortcut with hibernate enabled on PC

Tags: windows-8, sleep

I'm trying to create a shortcut for sleepmode but every site I found says it is not possible with hibernate enabled on PC.

The best suggestion I found was:

```
powercfg -hibernate off
start /min "" %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Standby
powercfg -hibernate on
```

However, this still puts the computer into hibernate instead of sleep.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and found a workaround which I can live with:
With the combination `Win+X`you can open the little Menu at the bottom.
By pressing `U` afterwards, you open the Menu "Shut down or sign out" which contains

- S **i** gn out
- **S** leep
- **H** ibernate
- Sh **u** t down
- **R** estart

This way you have at least a predefined "Sleep" shortcut by pressing

```
Win+X + U + S
```